# Microcontroller Interface IC

Tags: microcontroller, pic, integrated-circuit, interface, capacity

I am planning to communicate from my [dsPIC33FJ64GS608 Microcontroller](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70000591f.pdf) with a [HEF4894B IC](http://www.distrelec.de/Web/Downloads/_t/ds/hef4894_eng_tds.pdf?mime=application%2Fpdf).
Because of the Microcontroller is running at 3.3V I want to drive the IC also with 3.3V.
According to the data sheet this seems to be ok.
But there is something I am not sure about.

Is it safe to connect the output of the Microcontroller directly to the input of the IC so can I omit R1-R4 or because of the capacity of the IC inputs I should always put a resistor in between to limit the current flow?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRYy9E.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can omit those resistors without problems. The shift-register pins are high-impedance inputs and cannot overload the dsp outputs.

If you were connecting to output pins on an external chips, such resistors would be a good idea to prevent damage in case you were to accidentally set the dsp pins as outputs also, driving opposite states.